# Log Linear Models: Interpretation when None Fit

Tags: self-study, categorical-data, goodness-of-fit, contingency-tables, log-linear

This is question 9.6 from Categorical Data Analysis by Alan Agresti (Wiley, 2013).

The question asks us to find a Log Linear with the best fit for a 2x2x2 contingency table. The following are the explanatory variables.

- **A**: Abortion should be legal for any reason (yes or no)
- **T**: Willing to pay higher taxes to help the environment (yes or no)
- **P**: Political party affiliation (Democratic, Republican)

Here is my output from R.

```
                G^2      x^2 DF  p-value G^2  p-value X^2
(A,T,P)    44.95596 45.47235  4 4.060666e-09 3.171144e-09
(TP,A)     26.11294 25.39128  3 9.031946e-06 1.278875e-05
(AP,T)     32.81293 31.65649  3 3.526977e-07 6.182630e-07
(AT,P)     39.46998 34.14721  3 1.380028e-08 1.844369e-07
(AT,AP)    27.32695 25.30322  2 1.164201e-06 3.202402e-06
(AT,TP)    20.62696 19.11921  2 3.318271e-05 7.052056e-05
(AP,TP)    13.96991 13.56004  2 9.257053e-04 1.136252e-03
(AT,AP,TP) 11.61972 10.94716  1 6.525633e-04 9.374717e-04
(ATP)       0.00000  0.00000  0 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
```

How do we interpret this result?

What do we do when *none* of all of the possible log linear models fit?

My hunch is that the model (ATP) does fit, but can I justify that assumption given the model is saturated?

Would it be valid to make up a dummy variable to show the model (ATP) does fit well?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

ATP fits. This is trivially true. We could have known this without looking at the data. This is because it is a saturated model, so it can *exactly* reproduce your data. The problem with ATP is not the fit, but whether or not it is a model. A model is a simplification of your data, and ATP does not simplify but just exactly reproduce your data.

You can see this in another way. The null hypothesis of the tests you report is: There is no difference between the model you test and a fully saturated model. Again it is trivially true that the we cannot reject that null hypothesis for the model ATP, though that is not a very informative finding...

You can also question whether statistical tests are the right tool for choosing models. Again, a model is supposed to simplify your data. Simplify means being (somewhat) wrong. So the fact that we reject the null-hypothesis for the other models is in itself not a problem for that model. It would become a problem if the difference between the model and the data is so large that the model is no longer useful. The $p$-value is *not* a measure of usefulness, so it cannot be used to make that judgement call. Instead you need to interpret the models, compare them and see if you find the differences too big or not for your purpose.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified that I understand the saturated model fits in the trivial sense. I'd like to know in the context of the social situation analysis, can we say that in the true population three-way interaction exist between A T P . Also, I don't quite understand your point about the p-value, how would we assess the differences between the models without the p-value? To me, the p-value seems pretty usefull for assessing (or measuring) fit. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the contingency table used in this question:

```
surv.gss <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), E = c(1L, 1L
, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), P = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), count = c(50L, 5L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 27L, 50L, 61L)), .Names = c("A", 
"E", "P", "count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Print data:

```
> surv.gss
  A E P count
1 1 1 1    50
2 1 1 0     5
3 1 0 1    28
4 1 0 0    30
5 0 1 1    32
6 0 1 0    27
7 0 0 1    50
8 0 0 0    61
```

Fit the saturated model:

```
require(car)
mod.gss <- glm(count ~ A * E * P, poisson, surv.gss)
Anova(mod.gss)
```

Which outputs Type II Anova (i.e. conforming to the marginality principle):

```
> Anova(mod.gss)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: count
      LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
A      11.5595  1  0.0006740 ***
E      10.7574  1  0.0010386 ** 
P       4.8513  1  0.0276248 *  
A:E     2.3502  1  0.1252675    
A:P     9.0072  1  0.0026891 ** 
E:P    15.7072  1  7.394e-05 ***
A:E:P  11.6197  1  0.0006526 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

With higher-order terms in the model, we need to look at the Anova table from bottom to top. We reject the null for `A:E:P` (i.e. the "three-way interaction"), which means that the partial association between each pair of variables varies over the levels of the third variable.

As mentioned in the other answer, the model fits the data perfectly, as shown by the lack-of-fit test (based on residual deviance) with a very large p value:

```
> mod.gss

Call:  glm(formula = count ~ A * E * P, family = poisson, data = surv.gss)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            A            E            P          A:E          A:P          E:P  
     4.1109      -0.7097      -0.8150      -0.1989      -0.9767       0.1299       0.3687  
      A:E:P  
     2.0028  

Degrees of Freedom: 7 Total (i.e. Null);  0 Residual
Null Deviance:      72.12 
Residual Deviance: 2.687e-14    AIC: 57.81

> pchisq(0, df=0, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 1
```